# Getting a full stack trace with Django-piston

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I just started using `django-piston`.

Usually, in Django, when my views throw an exception (and I'm in `DEBUG=True` mode), I get a really nice, helpful 500-error page with stack trace.

But when my Django-piston enabled views throw an exception instead of a nice stack trace page, I get a simple error page with only the exception message printed out.

For example...

```
Piston/0.2.3rc1 (Django 1.3) crash report:

Method signature does not match.

Signature should be: domain

Exception was: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
```

**How do I get the helpful Django stack trace pages back?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a sort-of non-answer to my own question.

It seems like [Django Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston) is an almost-dead project. I switched to using [Django Tastypie](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston).